# how to remove ubuntu compleletly from my laptop and install windows?

Tags: 12.04, software-center, firefox, uninstall, unsupported-packages

i have bought an laptop with Ubuntu version 12.04 and i want to remove it completely from laptop and install windows but i can't and i don't know how to uninstall it , So could anyone tell me please how to remove it ?

Answer (score 0):

You remove an OS by installing another one over it.

If you want to install Ubuntu during the installation process you get asked where to install Ubuntu and you can then remove partitions and recreate them for that installation. This removing also removes the currently present operating system.

Windows has a similar method (but how that works has no relation to Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

Just like  Rinzwind said just  install your Windows Os on it.

You need to make  proper  bios settings if you do not see the installation interface.

Answer (score 0):

Boot into windows live disk.During the installation process,select custom  option and format the partition where ubuntu is installed.Don't forgot to install the windows os in a **primary partition**.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed Ubuntu alongside with Windows go to Control Panel and remove Ubuntu.
If not, do you have any disk to install Windows?